# finding which groups was found using a regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to match following strings

```
foo=boo-40
foo=1*boo+0
foos=1/10*boo+0
foos=1*boo-32000
foos=boo*1
foos=boo*1/10
```

usingregex.

For doing that, I am using following regex:

```
'[(foo|foos)]=(?P<Pnum1>\d+)?(/?P<Pdenom1>\d+)?\*?\(?boo\)?\*?(?P<Pnum2>\d+)?(/?P<Pdenom2>\d+)?(?P<Poffset>[+-]\d+)?'
```

My problem is assuming Pnum1 was not found, rather then Pnum2 was found.

how do i detect which Pnum1 or Pnum2 was found?

I tried the following:

```
try:
    if match.group('Pnum1'):
        Pnum = match.group('Pnum1')
    elif match.group('Pnum2'):
        Pnum = match.group('Pnum2')
    else:
        Pnum = None
except IndexError:
        Pnum = None
```

But this test is wrong, since in case 'Pnum1' does not exist, the code does not test for 'Pnum2' (It can be that none of them exists).

Is it possible to retrieve the found match elements? or to return a default value from `match.group('Pnum2')` (like get in dictionary)?

Comment: The group is `None` when it was not found, so you could test for this condition: `if match.group('Pnum1') is not None:`

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but in Python you should name your variables with lower case and keep capitals for class names.

Comment: Your code *does* check `Pnum2` when `Pnum1` does not exist, and if neither does, it sets `Pnum` to `None`. So what are you after exactly? Please clarify, because your question is unclear and risks being closed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the regexp is correct, it's better if, instead of a test, you simply do:

```
Pnum = match.group('Pnum1') or match.group('Pnum2')
```

As `or` returns the first *truthy* value or the last *falsy*, if `'Pnum1'` is not `None`, the variable will get the value from `'Pnum1'`. If its `None`, then the value from `'Pnum2'`. If both are `None`, it will become `None`.

Notice this gives preference to the term you put first in the `or` expression.

Comment: thank you for your solution. I got following error:    Pdenom = match.group('Pdenom1') or match.group('Pdenom2')
IndexError: no such group, where match is not None